# Setting one field of Composite primary key to AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment, alter

How to set one of the field of a primary key(composed of two fields of data type varchar(10) and int) of int data type to AUTO_INCREMENT, after declaring the primary key. Can we do it using ALTER command?

Comment: Why bother can't you just add a unique key based on varchar column, ai column?

Comment: You can, using the MyISAM engine, but don't. Just store a surrogate AI instead, and calculate the user-friendly value as and when you need it.

Comment: In innodb an AI column can be part of a composite primary key but it must be the first node which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: I can't really see the use case for this question. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @P.Salmon I can, but just curious about my query.

Comment: @Strawberry I have just started doing MySQL. Its new to me. And MyISAM is newer. Would you like to explain this please in more elaborate manner?

Comment: Mysql has many database engines if which innodb and myisam are 2 - but they all have different features..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD PRIMARY KEY( `id`, `name`);

ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: Unless already using MyISAM, I'm not sure what this achieves !?!?